# XAML: Applying styles to nested controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

In WPF, Prism v4, I have a ToolBar which acts as a region. In this region I inject UserControls which contains buttons and separators for the toolbar.
The problem is that because the buttons now lives in a UserControl, the toolbar styles no longer applies.

I *could* solve this by defining the styles:

```
<Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}"/>
<Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"/>
```

But I would like to avoid this because I got hundreds of buttons. So my question is if I can define styles for all buttons under the ToolBar from a resource dictionary?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
<Style TargetType="Separator" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" />
```

If you put that in your ToolBar resources, then it will apply to any buttons inside it.

Comment: Will this also apply to any views injected dynamically ?

Answer (score 6):

The same techniques mentioned by CodeNaked and Marat Khasanov can also be utilized in a default ToolBar style so you don't have to reset them locally.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolBar}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" />
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <!-- etc... -->
    </Style>
```

I expected this to be the default behavior of ToolBar but I found that it required explicit definition.

Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

Put base styles into ToolBar resources:

```
<ToolBar>
    <ToolBar.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"/>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}"/>
    </ToolBar.Resources>
    ...
</ToolBar>
```