# Why Resource style isn't applied to Separator but directly applied style works?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5663186/11728990) by @CodeNaked, but somehow I'm struggling with applying it to a `Menu` separator. It doesn't apply the `Style` I define in my `Resources`.

Here is my code:

```xml
<Menu>
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="Separator" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
    </Menu.Resources>

    <MenuItem Header="Foo"></MenuItem>
    <Separator/>
    <MenuItem Header="Bar"></MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

If I explicitly set the `Style` on the `Separator`, it works.

```xml
<Separator Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}"/>
```

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work in the first case?

Comment: Does it work for `MenuItem ` though?

Comment: The Style for MenuItem works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your style with:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="Separator" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.SeparatorStyleKey}}" />
```

See MSDN documentation for [Separator Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.separator?view=netframework-4.8):

> When you create a Menu with a Separator, the **control automatically
>   applies the Style identified by the MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey
>   property**. Styles are placed in resource dictionaries and **are
>   searched for by their keys**. To change the Style of a Separator inside
>   a Menu, you must use the MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey property to create
>   your new Style.

So the resource style for separator will be overridden from control and if it being put directly to the control - not.

Comment: Why isn't styling a consistent thing in WPF? why did they need this special rule for the `Separator` class?

Comment: I don't know whether there are any reason for.